# VBA from tag to bold

Tags: excel, vba

in Excel, I have different data in several rows containing bold tags like this :

```
bonjour, <b>je</b> voudrais <b>savoir</b> un truc
```

i need to transform the text between tags in bold and strip away the tags in all the spreadsheet. Here's the result I'm looking for :

bonjour, **je** voudrais **savoir** un truc

Since I'm starting on VBA, I've grabbed some portions of code from other forums to try to achieve this, but all it can do is make the transformation one row at a time. I would like this macro to run on all the spreadsheet.

Do you guys have any idea how to get that done ?

Heres's the code :

```
Option Explicit
Sub testme01()

Dim str As String
Dim nBold() As Long
Dim nEndBold() As Long
Dim nChars() As Long
Dim nTimes As Long
Dim iCtr As Long

With ActiveCell
str = .Text
nTimes = (Len(str) - Len(Replace(str, "<b>", ""))) / Len("<b>")
If nTimes = 0 Then
'do nothing
Else
ReDim nBold(1 To nTimes)
ReDim nEndBold(1 To nTimes)
ReDim nChars(1 To nTimes)

For iCtr = 1 To nTimes
nBold(iCtr) = InStr(str, "<b>")
nEndBold(iCtr) = InStr(nBold(iCtr), str, "</b>")
If nEndBold(iCtr) = 0 Then
nEndBold(iCtr) = 32767
End If
nChars(iCtr) = nEndBold(iCtr) - nBold(iCtr) - 3
str = Replace(Replace(str, "<b>", "", 1, 1), "</b>", "", 1, 1)
Next iCtr

str = Replace(str, "</b>", "")
.Value = str

For iCtr = 1 To nTimes
.Characters(nBold(iCtr), nChars(iCtr)).Font.Bold = True
Next iCtr

End If
End With
End Sub
```

Thanx :)

Comment: I see you're using loops. Have you tried extending the concept to iterate rows? Also, I'd suggest you *indent* your code - with everything stuck to the left it's pretty hard to tell which loop/conditional starts/ends where.

Answer (score 0):

have you Sub accept a `Range` variable as its argument (say it's called `cell`) and then call it form inside a loop of an outer "Main" Sub

like follows:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim cell As Range

    With Worksheets("bolds") '<--| change "bolds" to your actual worksheet name
        For Each cell In .UsedRange.SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues)
            ProcessBolds cell
        Next cell
    End With
End Sub

Sub ProcessBolds(cell As Range)
    Dim str As String
    Dim nBold() As Long
    Dim nEndBold() As Long
    Dim nChars() As Long
    Dim nTimes As Long
    Dim iCtr As Long

    With cell
        str = .Text
        nTimes = (Len(str) - Len(Replace(str, "<b>", ""))) / Len("<b>")
        If nTimes = 0 Then
            'do nothing
        Else
            ReDim nBold(1 To nTimes)
            ReDim nEndBold(1 To nTimes)
            ReDim nChars(1 To nTimes)

            For iCtr = 1 To nTimes
                nBold(iCtr) = InStr(str, "<b>")
                nEndBold(iCtr) = InStr(nBold(iCtr), str, "</b>")
                If nEndBold(iCtr) = 0 Then
                    nEndBold(iCtr) = 32767
                End If
                nChars(iCtr) = nEndBold(iCtr) - nBold(iCtr) - 3
                str = Replace(Replace(str, "<b>", "", 1, 1), "</b>", "", 1, 1)
            Next iCtr

            str = Replace(str, "</b>", "")
            .Value = str

            For iCtr = 1 To nTimes
                .Characters(nBold(iCtr), nChars(iCtr)).Font.Bold = True
            Next iCtr
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```